# Preorientation of additive formal group

Tags: homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, formal-groups, ring-spectra

In *"[A Survey of Elliptic Cohomology](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-01200-6_9)"*, Section 3.2, Lurie asserts that the preorientations of the additive formal group $\widehat{\mathbf G}_a$ over $\mathbf Z$ are classified by the $\mathbb E_\infty$-ring $\mathbf Z[\mathbf{CP}^\infty]$. That is to say, there should be a homotopy equivalence between the space of maps of topological abelian groups $\mathbf{CP}^\infty\to \widehat{\mathbf G}_a(A)$, and maps of $\mathbb E_\infty$(-$\mathbf Z$?)-algebras $\mathbf Z[\mathbf{CP}^\infty]\to A$.

***I don't understand why that should be.***

Lurie claims that one can obtain this by a similar computation as the one he carries out in a prior section for the multiplicative group $\widehat{\mathbf G}_m$, where we indeed get $S[\mathbf{CP}^\infty]$. That computation I have no issues with — it boils down to the adjunction $\Sigma^\infty_+\Omega^\infty :\mathrm{CAlg}^\mathrm{cn}\leftrightarrows \mathrm{Sp}^\mathrm{cn}:\mathrm{gl}_1$. But that seems completely unapplicable in the case of the additive formal group ….

Instead, it looks to me like the preorientations of $\widehat{\mathbf G}_a$ should instead be classified by the free $\mathbb E_\infty$-ring $\mathrm{Sym}^*(\Sigma^2\mathbf Z)$. *Is that the claim?* That this is (possibly after base-changing along $S\to\mathbf Z$)
for some reason equivalent to the group $\mathbb E_\infty$-ring of $\mathbf{CP}^\infty$?

Comment: Is it not the Dold--Thom theorem?

Comment: @PavelSafronov: Ooh, that sounds promising! Any chance you could spell this out a bit more though, maybe in the form of an answer? I don't quite see how to apply the DT theorem - it talks about a sequential limit of symmetric powers - how does that translate to the free E∞-algebras here? But then, I don't really understand Dold-Thom very well...

Comment: The definition of a preorientation of a formal group $\mathbf{G}$ depends only on the underlying formal scheme of $\mathbf{G}$ (together with a base point). Over $\mathbf{Z}$, the formal additive and multiplicative groups are isomorphic as formal schemes (via the map $t \mapsto t+1$).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you for the clarification!